# Custom sorting with Excel

Tags: excel

Good evening community.  I have one column with about 250 pieces of equipment; from cell 1 to 250. For example:

```
San.Brn.Ess.1111A.BYP
San.Brn.Ess.1111B.BYP
San.Vib.Pcp.1222B.H_SP
Tel.Tcp.Elp.1243A1.HH_TRP
Tan.Del.Fet.3345B1.L_SP
Tec.Fan.Tel.6765C1.LL_TRP
Ghg.Ran.Trk.2123A.TOT
Ghg.Ran.Trk.2123B.TOT
```

I need to sort the data by the end of the equipment name in this exact order:

```
.BYP
.H_SP
.HH_TRP
.L_SP
.LL_TRP
.TOT
```

I attempted to do a custom sort in excel with the exact same order mentioned above and I did not have much luck. I'm not versed in vba nor equations to accomplish the above request. What would be the best course of action to complete this request? Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Duplicate just the rightmost part of the equipment in an adjacent column; then sort by that column using your Custom List.  If that doesn't work for you, show us the steps you've taken, and the results at each step.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Ron. Unsuccessfully.  I created the sort first. I went into "sort and filtet" and selected "custom sort." Selected "custom list" from "order" drop down menu. Added .byp, .h_sp, etc....  I then added the tags on column A and the order in which to sort the tags in on column B (.byp, h_sp, etc). Highlighted both columns, selected "sort and filter" "custom sort" and ensured I was sorting by cloumn B, sorting values and selected the drop down menu that I created with the endings of the tags (.byp, h_sp, l_sp, etc).  I tried wild cards but I did not work. Ideas?

Comment: as an aside. I put your trailing items (the ones in column 2 of @RonRosenfeld's answer) into excel and did a normal sort, and they sort correctly by Excel's default... Once you have them separated from the rest of the string.

Comment: @guitarthrower That is true, of course, and, if there are no other suffixes, would eliminate the need to use a custom list.  With 250 pieces of equipment, I wasn't sure of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fairly straightforward.  Not sure what you did incorrectly. Perhaps these screen shots will help:

Original Data with formula to return the right most sorting characters:

[image: Original]

Data/Sort with Custom List showing:

[image: Data/Sort Custom]

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: Ron.  That worked.  You were correct.  User error. Im a victim of the Id10t syndrome. Foreign language keyboard and auto correct software pre-installed on these machines. I need some sleep. Ron, my humblest apologies for wasting your time. The formula you provided is greatly appreciated. Thank you. Have a great day.

Comment: @user2847718 Thank you. Also note that, as pointed out by guitarthrower, your suffixes are already in alphabetical order, so, if there are no other suffixes to account for, you don't really need a custom list.